# Any free 2D C\C++ framework that supports iPhone?

Tags: c++, iphone, c

I'm looking for a C\C++ game dev framework that supports iPhone.
It should have least Objective-C requirement to use it.

The closest one I could find is Kanji engine.
But that's not free.

Other frameworks like cocos2d need to be code in obj-c.

So do you know any C\C++ game dev framework for iPhone?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airplay SDK works well.

http://www.airplaysdk.com/

I've used it with the express edition of Visual Studio. It comes with a decent emulator for windows too, and supports more than just iPhone platform:

- iPhone OS
- Android
- Samsung Bada
- Symbian
- Windows Mobile
- BREW
- Palm/HP webOS
- Maemo

.. it also has pretty generous Indie licensing terms. The iphone/ipod/ipad license is free. Other platforms are available for $99 per seat/year if you earn < $100k per year.

http://www.airplaysdk.com/licensing_details

Answer (score 4):

[Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/) is a C/C++ 2D cross-platform programming library. They don't mention iPhone as a supported platform on the website, but it appears there in [the recent changelog](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/changes.html), so probably you can grab the development version and find something useful there.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) on a project. It's pretty neat and easy to understand.

Comment: That's objective-c. Right?

Comment: yup, except for box2d/chipmunk of course

Answer (score 1):

This might be of interest:
http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/

Comment: But that's for 3D.

Comment: Well, nothing is stopping you from not working in the third dimension.

Comment: I agree with Nailer, but sure, a "pure 2D" library might be easier to work with. I haven't worked enough on embedded systems to give you any other recommendations though.

Comment: As soon as you want one sprite in front of another sprite, you're doing 3D.

Comment: No you're not. You can do that by sorting the rendering order and stay in 2D.

Answer (score 1):

### [Angel Engine](http://code.google.com/p/angel-engine/)

I don't know that the stable version supports iPhone yet, but it does support Mac OSX.  There is a development branch thats specifically to enable iPhone support.

Answer (score 1):

Ogre3d (www.ogre3d.org) supports pretty much everything, and includes an SDK for iPhone development as well (OGRESDK/SDK/iPhone directory). It is free so no worries about any fees for using it. It is primarily a 3d rendering engine, although plenty of people have used it for 2D work, so if that is a problem you might want to look at some of the 2D options listed above.